# virtualization and visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, vmware, virtualization

Is it possible using windows 7 or windows server 2008 to create 5 VMWare virtual machines
so that 5 developers can use them using thin clients to work with 
Visual Studio 2008/2010 with all components (sql server express, IIS etc). 
what can be the options and the hardware specs for server and clients?

I am looking forward for all opinions.

Thanks and Regards.

Comment: This question would probably be better answered on http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly *possible* as long as you have enough cores, RAM and Windows/VS licenses.  I often use Hyper-V for testing different Visual Studio installations, though I haven't had more than 2 running at the same time.  I think you can pull this off, but you'll probably want 16GB of RAM and an 8-core processor.  I'm not sure what problems you might run into with VMWare, but I think it would work with Hyper-V.

Good luck!